# Laravel with Vite: Issue with infinite loading when adding `@vite('resources/css/app.css')` to view

Tags: javascript, laravel, tailwind-css, vite

I am currently facing an issue when trying to load my Laravel application with Vite. Specifically, when I add the `@vite('resources/css/app.css')` directive to my view, the loading process seems to hang indefinitely. However, if I remove the `@vite` directive, the loading works without css.

I suspect that there might be a problem with tailwind or another factor that is causing this issue. Here are some additional details and steps I have taken:

Environment Details:

- Operating System: WSL Ubuntu
- PHP Version: 8.1.2
- Laravel Framework Version: 10.15.0
- Vite Version: 4.4.3
- Vite configuration:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

- Blade template:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>aaa</title>
  @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>

<body class="bg-white">
  @yield('content')
</body>

</html>
```

- Error messages: theres no erro messages in chrome console, npm run dev and, php artisan serve

I have tried searching for solutions, but I couldn't find any that addressed this specific issue. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!